# How to leave browser opened even after selenium ruby script finishes

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I am using a ruby script with selenium web-driver, for automating an web page login. The issue is after script finishes it closes the browser also. I want to keep the browser opened even after the script finishes. Is there any way by which I can keep browser open after the test do something else with the browser window?

I am doing like this.

```
if browser == "Firefox"
     driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
end

if stack == "example.com"
      driver.get "http://www.example.com/tests/
end

element = driver.find_element :name => "email"
element.clear
element.send_keys username

element = driver.find_element :name => "password"
element.clear
element.send_keys password

element = driver.find_element :name => "commit"
element.submit
```

===================================================

Answer (score 13):

I've never actually tried using `selenium-webdriver` in a standalone script like that, but I have run into the same problem using `selenium-webdriver` within the context of `capybara`/`cucumber`.

Looking at the source code for `capybara`, I found this hook which explicitly closes the browser after your script is finished. If you're *not* using `selenium-webdriver` with `capybara`, then this might not be helpful, but it was helpful for me...

`gems/capybara-1.1.1/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb` registers an `at_exit` hook, which then calls `quit` on the browser object:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

class Capybara::Selenium::Driver < Capybara::Driver::Base
  ...

  def browser
    unless @browser
      @browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for(options[:browser], options.reject { |key,val| SPECIAL_OPTIONS.include?(key) })

      main = Process.pid
      at_exit do
        # Store the exit status of the test run since it goes away after calling the at_exit proc...
        @exit_status = $!.status if $!.is_a?(SystemExit)
        quit if Process.pid == main
        exit @exit_status if @exit_status # Force exit with stored status
      end
    end
    @browser
  end
```

You should be able to monkey-patch the `quit` method so that it does nothing, like so:

```
  Selenium::WebDriver::Driver.class_eval do
    def quit
      #STDOUT.puts "#{self.class}#quit: no-op"
    end
  end
```

Note: If you are using `Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome` and `chromedriver` 
-- which you *aren't*, but other people might be -- I noticed that it also kills the `chromedriver` process, and as soon as that "service" process is killed, the Chrome *browser* process that was connected to it also quits.

So I had to also prevent that service process from stopping, like so:

```
    Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service.class_eval do
      def stop
        #STDOUT.puts "#{self.class}#stop: no-op"
      end
    end
```

There was one other problem I ran into, which probably won't affect you, unless you're using this driver with **cucumber**... Even after I got it to leave the browser open, it would be left open on the "about:blank" page. It looks like this is triggered by this hook:

gems/capybara-1.1.1/lib/capybara/cucumber.rb:

```
After do
  Capybara.reset_sessions!
end
```

Which calls gems/capybara-1.1.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:70:in `reset!'"

Which calls gems/capybara-1.1.1/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:80:in `reset!'":

```
  def reset!
    ...
    @browser.navigate.to('about:blank')
    ...
  end
```

And I solved that with another monkey-patch:

```
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.class_eval do
    def reset!
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 13):

A quick hack that worked for me:

sleep(9000)

in your test gives you a fair amount of time to play around with the browser before the driver closes it.

Comment: I presume this would block a single threaded server being debugged from serving other requests from a browser :(

Answer (score 12):

This is the code that worked for me with Capybara

```
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.class_eval do
  def quit
    puts "Press RETURN to quit the browser"
    $stdin.gets
    @browser.quit
  rescue Errno::ECONNREFUSED
    # Browser must have already gone
  end
end
```

It's a monkey patching of what I found in gems/capybara-1.1.2/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb

I just added the puts and the gets lines. Selenium::WebDriver::Driver was giving me a not found error probably because I'm getting selenium from within capybara.

This is useful to see what's the code that generated an error but there is a downside: the browser stops past the last page and displays a blank screen. I have to click the back button to get to the page with the error which might not always work. Does anybody know why the browser loads that empty page and save me the time to dig into the capybara code? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you run the test with debugging enabled and drop a debugger line at the end it should leave the browser open. Look at the [ruby-debug gem](https://github.com/mark-moseley/ruby-debug). It also might be worth checking out this Railscast about [Pry](http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails).

Comment: That would definitely be the easiest solution, if you're okay with pausing the execution of your script. If you wanted your script to finish/quit and *still* leave the browser open, this solution wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Here some snippet in Python:

Putting this at the end of your script, will leave the browser windows open and ends the script when it is closed manually (requires some imports at the beginning):

```
import time
import sys
...
while 1:
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
       b = browser.find_by_tag("body")      
    except:
      sys.exit()
```

Comment: Note for users of more recent versions of Selenium: I found that I had to change `find_by_tag` to `find_element_by_tag_name`.

Comment: this just opens the browser, insta closes it, then opens it again after  minutes in python Splinter (which uses selenium which uses chromedriver) but behaviour can differ.

Answer (score 2):

Watir's `until` function will hold the script until a condition returns true. Set the timeout to infinity and check for all the windows to be closed.

```
Watir::Wait.until(timeout: Float::INFINITY) {@browser.windows.length == 0}
@browser.close
```

Put this at the end of your script and close all the tabs manually to exit.

Comment: Edited to explain.

Answer (score 1):

This is largely what the other commenters have said already about overriding quit on the driver, but here's the simplified code I ended up using for a standalone Capybara script:

```
require 'capybara'

session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
session.driver.class.class_eval { def quit; end }
session.visit('http://localhost:3000')
# ... other stuff
```

Assuming you have a web server running on localhost:3000, this will launch Firefox, navigate to this URL and leave the browser window open.

Answer (score 0):

What test framework are you using?

Usually your test framework has some sort of `setup` and `teardown` methods that you can define which allows you to start the browser

```
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
```

in the setup method, and destroy the browser

```
@driver.quit
```

in teardown.

Just put some logic around the teardown portion of your scripts to only destroy the browser when you want to.